# Central G-module

Tags: group-theory, modules

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be a $G$-module. I stumbled upon a term Central $G$-module in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.03346.pdf). When do we say $A$ is Central? Any ideas will be helpful.

For the Definition of $G$-module you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module

Comment: It would help you also provide a reference to where you found this terminology.

Comment: I have put the reference in the question. Please check that out.

Comment: Where in the paper do they use this term? I text-searched for "central G-module", but found nothing. There are 148 instances of the word "central" and 103 of the word "module", so more help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you please check the reference again? I changed the reference. In the above-mentioned paper, you will find this terminology easily.

Comment: Edited my answer. It seems to be right now

Answer (score 2):

It just means that the action is a scalar.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: The action is a mapping $x$ to $x^n$ for some $n$. In the particular case from that paper, it has order $2$, so it's $x\mapsto -x$ (or $x^{-1}$ using multiplicative notation).

Comment: How did you come up with this idea? My question is why did they use the term Central?

Comment: Because $Z$ is the centre of the group, because such an action means that the group lies in the centre of $\mathrm{GL}(Z)$, or for another reason. It's definitely non-standard terminology,

Comment: Okay. Can we generalize this term for an arbitrary $G$-module $A$? In that case, $A$ can't be the center of the group, as $A$  is not a part of $G$.

Comment: The group $G$ would have to act as scalars on $A$, i.e., any group element $g$ acts as $x\mapsto n_g\cdot x$ for some $n_g\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yeah. It makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Except there's definitely a mistake in the definition of $Z$ on the top of p5. $\mathrm{SL}(2,2)=\mathrm{GL}(2,2)$, so his definition of $R_G(Z)$ is wrong.